# WebGL not working

Tags: firefox, plugins, webgl

I have Ubuntu Mate 15.10, and Firefox 44, and I am trying to play eyewire from eyewire.org. Persistently I get errors. I have tried modifying the WebGL options in about config to force webGL to run, but I still get the error. 
[image]

I have tried [other AU Q&A posts](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1oI2D48vNAhXqy4MKHQYpC3wQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F53452%2Fhow-do-i-enable-webgl-in-firefox&usg=AFQjCNF5lb0rEk4wv5ULQhWfJjZwcvmM2w&sig2=zfCr4F9KDc-HEDtg5IpBCA), but the results are the same 
I tried installing  libosmesa6 but I already have it, and it is up
to date. 
I have a FireGL Graphics card.